# url is not working for BIM 360 API issue identifer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

url ->
'issues/v1/containers/c07fd127-b03b-4fa0-bfad-bd82ee4e2fa7/quality-issues?page[limit]=64&filter[identifier]=1'

error message ->
Error: {"message":"Request failed with status code 400","response":{"errors":[{"title":"Filter not allowed","detail":"identifier is not allowed.","code":"102","status":"400"}]}}

breakpoint ->
let response = await this.get(url, headers, ReadTokenScopes);

Comment: `filter[identifier]` is not described as a filter you can use, in the documentation. The response is explicit. You could check the documentation [Get Issues](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/) to get allowed filters.

Comment: thanks Alex, well, looks like identifier is not on the list, i assume identifier cannot be used for sorting? any factory people here to comment? looks like OOTB BIM 360 issue has no problem at least for sorting based on identifier

Comment: It seems unsupported, unfortunately.. I'm double-checking with our engineering team, but again, it would have some expected delays due to the winder break.

Comment: thanks Eason and have a great weekend!

Comment: hi Eason, any feedback from engineering team? will be great if this can be fixed soon, any tangible date, say within 3 months? well, this affects sorting which is quite big problem, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, filter[identifier] is unsupported in v1 API as well as the filter[assignedTo].